# Touch another UITextField don't work (sometimes)

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield

I have 2 textfields. On startup I can switch between lbl and lbl2. But after the first click only lbl is working, you have to tap 10(+/-) times on lbl2 before the cursor goes to that textfield. Whats going on?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UITextField *lbl = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 397, 266, 30)];

    [lbl setPlaceholder:@"E-mailadres"];
    [lbl setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];

    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[self view] addSubview:lbl];

    CALayer* layer = [lbl layer];

    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer.frame.size.height-1, layer.frame.size.width, 1);
    [bottomBorder setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];


    UITextField *lbl2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 450, 266, 30)];

    [lbl2 setPlaceholder:@"Wachtwoord"];
    [lbl2 setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    [lbl2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    lbl2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl2.secureTextEntry = YES;
    [[self view] addSubview:lbl2];


    CALayer* layer2 = [lbl2 layer];

    CALayer *bottomBorder2 = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder2.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder2.borderWidth = 1;
    bottomBorder2.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer2.frame.size.height-1, layer2.frame.size.width, 1);
    [bottomBorder2 setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [layer2 addSublayer:bottomBorder2];

    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(24, 500, 266, 30); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:@"INLOGGEN" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    // add to a view
    [[self view] addSubview:myButton];

    CALayer *layer3 = myButton.layer;
    layer3.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    layer3.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    layer3.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    layer3.opacity = 0.6;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but you really shouldn't be doing this stuff in `viewWillAppear:`, as this can be called several times, in which case you'll have multiple textviews on top of each other. Move this code to `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: I moved the code. But still same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears neither text field was given a delegate. I'm not sure you can use them without one - I never tried. If you don't have a delegate how would you dismiss the keyboard at the end of the editing session?

Comment: There are no required UITextView delegate methods.

Comment: Well, what do I do in similar circumstance? Make myself delegate, and log the ones that ask OK to edit, and OK to stop editing. See if you get any messages. No messages, your views are partially covered by some other view.